# RegEx pickup words after specific word

Tags: regex

Having a bit of the RegEx brain fart, and could really do with some kind assistance if anyone has time please?

I would like to pick up all words for URL after domain name.

For example:

> http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b08y26qp

Should return: `programmes`,`b08y26qp`

I have got this far:

```
[a-z][a-z0-9]*
```

But how do I qualify to begin returning words after `http://www.bbc.co.uk/`?

Very many thanks!

Comment: try such as [`\b/\K[^/]+`](https://regex101.com/r/eFAXkN/1)

Comment: Often times with regex you match more groups than you want, but just ignore a few. No reason you can't just match `/[^\/]+/` and ignore matches 1 (`http:`) and 2 (domain).

Comment: What language are you using? Regex differs depending on what code you are using. Add as a tag for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to prepend `http://www.bbc.co.uk/` as string literal to your regex. You should also use the string start anchor (`^`) to reduce work on a failed match (`^http:\/\/www\.bbc\.co\.uk\/`)

#### Online

You can go to https://regex101.com/, and just add a `\` before each (non grey) highlighted character until the whole regex only has grey highlights.

#### Java

In Java, just let `Pattern.quote(string)` and `Matcher.quoteReplacement(string)` do the escaping for you.

Of course, if you have a programming language, Something like this would be better. `urlString.substring("http://www.bbc.co.uk/".length()+1).split("/")`

Answer (score 1):

Using `$` you bind the regex to the end of the line. In this case it does matter what's in the begining.

Using `()` you can specify groups. This allows to retrieve results easily.

This regex applied to `http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b08y26qp`

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$
```

results in:

> Group 1: programmes
>   Group 2: b08y26qp

See this example also in regex 101: https://regex101.com/r/YkUHk5/1/